# Cleaning up code but not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to clean up my code a little. Here is what I have so far:

next class UPDATED***

```
    }
}



**ERRORS BELOW:**

 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g gradeSorter.java

gradeSorter.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    intNode good = new intNode();
    ^
  symbol:   class intNode
  location: class gradeSorter
gradeSorter.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    intNode good = new intNode();
                       ^
  symbol:   class intNode
  location: class gradeSorter
2 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

The code was not formatted before and was all a single file with no methods or classes. I'm trying to transfer it over. The program was working perfectly before. I don't know how to call a variable in the main class over to the subclass.

Comment: Can you try to indent your code properly?

Comment: Are the two classes in the same package? If not you need an import statement. Apart from that you have a few missing return statements in the methods that are supposed to return strings, and `scanner` and `fmt` are not defined anywhere. Once that is sorted it should compile.

Comment: You do not have any `package my.package.name;` lines. Java looks in the current package to find class that are not `import`ed.

Comment: both java files are not found in the same folder

Comment: @assylias, I'll try to make it a little more formatted. Also scanner and fmt are defined in the main class.

Comment: @SSpoke, wow you were right. I fixed it and the main class now works. Still have the same errors on the second class.

Comment: you have to use `javac -g gradeSorter.java` for first file `javac -g intNode.java` for second file.. looks like the errors are both for gradeSorter.java you never showed for `intNode.java`  it's recommanded you do `javac -g *.java` which does both files at once

Comment: For future reference, please leave the code in the main post - otherwise it mysteriously disappears.  If you have more questions, ask an **additional** one.  Oh, an IDE would probably _greatly_ help with the refactoring - most of them have tools to do things like extract classes (which would have solved your package problem automatically)

Answer (score 0):

First off standard Java style is Class names are capatilizaed unlike method names. I.E

```
public class GradeSorter;
```

I don't know if you're using the try catch how you want to use it.  Right when you try to find the file "grades.dat", if it generates an exception it them creates and intNode object.  If there is no exception your program ends.

EDIT:  You also create an intNode object using "new intNode();", now this will call the no-arg constructor of your intNode class which is non-existant, so as of now it calls the default one. to make this

```
public class intNode

{

   public intNode()
   {whatever you want when object is created}

}
```

Comment: added System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());

Comment: Okay nice, You need to also move that instatiation of the intNode object outside of the catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your classes do not appear to be in the same package. At the top of each file you should have a line with package information, like:

```
package mypack;
```

Classes that are in the same package can access each other's public fields and methods.
Note: if you compile your code with javac, the compilation command will be slightly different when classes are packaged. Read more about packages in Java, as this is what you probably need to fix your error.

**New information update:**

to access fmt from intNode, you need to have this variable declared outside the main method, and if you still want fmt to be initialized inside the main method, it may look like this:

```
public class GradeSorter{

    public static DecimalFormat fmt;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
    (...)
```

To access fmt from intNode now:

```
GradeSorter.fmt;
```

as it is a static variable bound to GradeSorter class. So your String expressions would be like

```
result += "The average of these grades is : " + GradeSorter.fmt.format(average);
result += "The standard deviation of these grades is: " + GradeSorter.fmt.format(deviation);
```

Also, notice that your String methods (toString(), frequency()) are missing return statements.

About formatting itself, there are many standards set for Java code (like method names are written like: thisIsMyMethod(); and classes are written like: ThisIsMyClass) as well as many standards for writing elegant and readable code in general (tabulation, bracing etc.) Internet (and book!) resources are just waiting to be (re)discovered.
And about Java itself you should study more about fields and methods in general, access modificators, differences between classes and objects (why static?) and about object oriented programming in general, as the code you posted appear to be chaotic and not structured well.

Comment: is "package" line on top of both files?

Comment: fixed yes. Put it on the very top.

Comment: What is the problem now? Still the same exception? Have you recompiled both files with their new "package" lines?

Comment: the problem is that I want to access the variable fmt and scanner from the main class but I don't know how to call them.

Comment: You must first declare them in grade sorter class but outside the main method. If you want to have them initialized inside the main method, you need to make them static. You can later access them this way: gradeSorter.fmt